# Coming from C++ background, trying to understand what callback is doing in this function from the Scrapy framework

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm following the basic Scrapy tutorial, and have some limited python experience. This seems like a recursive function, and I have some questions about what is happening.

This is in the Scrapy tutorial: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

This ran the same when I specified `callback=self.parse` and when I left it out.

Here's the code (the last line is where my question is coming from):

```
def parse(self, response):
    for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
        yield {
            'text':     quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
            'author':     quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first(),
            'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
        }

    next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

The function performs identically when I omit `callback=self.parse` and when I leave it in. 
Is this callback implicit, and not necessary? Is there a reason you need to have it in there?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I read this somewhere in the scrapy documentation ***If callback is None follow defaults to True , otherwise it defaults to False***. Even if you do not explicitly define callback within your script, It will still follow the default function which is `parse()` in this case. Hope it clears your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked explains what's happening in the [A shortcut to the start_requests method](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#a-shortcut-to-the-start-requests-method) section:

> `parse()` is Scrapy’s default callback method, which is called for requests without an explicitly assigned callback

The scrapy tutorial just shows the basic method, and then tries to ease you into using alternatives.

Comment: The reason the documentation leaves it in is so that you understand that you can change the callback name there to use a different callback. Otherwise, someone reading the documentation might wonder how to use a different callback, or worse, think it is not possible to use a different callback.